# Problema de inicio en Nextcloiud 19

Tags: php, backend, nextcloud

Hola a todos tuve que reiniciar mi servidor domestico donde tengo una instalación de nextcloud y cuando fui a ingresar por medio de la interfaz web me mostró lo siguiente en pantalla no permitiéndome el ingreso y rechazando todo tipo de conexiones:

```
    <?php
/**
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2016, ownCloud, Inc.
 *
 * @author Christoph Wurst <christoph@winzerhof-wurst.at>
 * @author Joas Schilling <coding@schilljs.com>
 * @author JÃ¶rn Friedrich Dreyer <jfd@butonic.de>
 * @author Lukas Reschke <lukas@statuscode.ch>
 * @author Morris Jobke <hey@morrisjobke.de>
 * @author Robin Appelman <robin@icewind.nl>
 * @author Roeland Jago Douma <roeland@famdouma.nl>
 * @author Sergio BertolÃ­n <sbertolin@solidgear.es>
 * @author Thomas MÃ¼ller <thomas.mueller@tmit.eu>
 * @author Vincent Petry <pvince81@owncloud.com>
 *
 * @license AGPL-3.0
 *
 * This code is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License, version 3,
 * as published by the Free Software Foundation.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU Affero General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License, version 3,
 * along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>
 *
 */

require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/versioncheck.php';

try {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/base.php';

    OC::handleRequest();
} catch (\OC\ServiceUnavailableException $ex) {
    \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($ex, ['app' => 'index']);

    //show the user a detailed error page
    OC_Template::printExceptionErrorPage($ex, 503);
} catch (\OC\HintException $ex) {
    try {
        OC_Template::printErrorPage($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getHint(), 503);
    } catch (Exception $ex2) {
        try {
            \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($ex, ['app' => 'index']);
            \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($ex2, ['app' => 'index']);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            // no way to log it properly - but to avoid a white page of death we try harder and ignore this one here
        }

        //show the user a detailed error page
        OC_Template::printExceptionErrorPage($ex, 500);
    }
} catch (\OC\User\LoginException $ex) {
    OC_Template::printErrorPage($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getMessage(), 403);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($ex, ['app' => 'index']);

    //show the user a detailed error page
    OC_Template::printExceptionErrorPage($ex, 500);
} catch (Error $ex) {
    try {
        \OC::$server->getLogger()->logException($ex, ['app' => 'index']);
    } catch (Error $e) {
        http_response_code(500);
        header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
        print("Internal Server Error\n\n");
        print("The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.\n");
        print("Please contact the server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.\n");
        print("More details can be found in the webserver log.\n");

        throw $ex;
    }
    OC_Template::printExceptionErrorPage($ex, 500);
}
```

---

No me permite conectarme de ninguna manera a nextcloud, agradezco de antemano toda la ayuda que puedan prestarme no quisiera tener que reinstalar de nuevo nextcloud, que fue lamentablemente lo que hice la ultima vez, el en un principio me dio un error de apache en la linea de configuración de nextcloud elimine la linea ya que eso no me permitía iniciar apache y luego de retirarla apache inicio correctamente pero ahora nextcloud no permite login, ni siquiera la aplicacion inicia a nivel de servidor.

Comment: ¿Puedes ingresar a cualquier otro script PHP sin problema? Cuando ves el código PHP en el navegador puede ser por dos causas: A) No hay intérprete de PHP en ejecución B) Estás tratando de acceder desde la ruta del script en disco y no desde un servidor web como `http://localhost`

Comment: Lo más probable es que hayas desactivado el módulo de PHP en el servidor Apache. ¿Podrías compartir el contenido del archivo que te generaba error y la línea que eliminaste?

Answer (score 0):

Hola el codigo que coloque mas arriba me sale al intentar ingresar como siempre desde el navegador, es literalmente lo que me muestra en este momento el navegador al ingresar por el http://127.0.0.0/nextcloud, cosa que no deberia ocurrir, deberia tener la ingresar esa direcccion la interfaz de inicio a la aplicacion, tengo por demas instalaciones de php, al hacer una simple busqueda de los archivos php.ini me da el siguiente resultado:

```
/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/5.6/phpdbg/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/phpdbg/php.ini
/etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.1/phpdbg/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.3/phpdbg/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/8.0/phpdbg/php.ini
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.4/php.ini-production.cli
```

Es posible que haya borrado algo antes de eso hice una limpieza de archivos que ya no necesitaba el servidor con un "autoremove", encuentro 2 temas en eso, 1. seria que tengo demasiadas versiones  de php instaladas y 2.que no tengo la menor idea de que pude haber borrado que es necesario para el correcto inicio de nextcloud

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
```

A mí me funcionó; y asegúrate de que todos los paquetes pertenecen a la misma versión de PHP.